# Array values not printing correctly

Tags: c++, arrays

[image: This is the output i am getting when i run the code shown in this image.]I wrote this code for printing the productions after eliminating left recursion.And also i stored these output productions in "all" array. when i print this array, only the last values are being printed with blank lines in the initial rows.How to resolve this problem?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;
class production
{
    private:
        char lhs;
        char rhs[10][10],nr[10][10],rs[10][10],all[30][30];
        int noa,m;
    public:
        production()
        {
            noa=0;m=0;
            for(int i=0;i<30;i++)
            for(int j=0;j<30;j++)
            all[i][j]='\0';
        }
        void makeprod(char *str)
        {
            noa=0;
            for(int i=0;i<30;i++)
            for(int j=0;j<30;j++)
            rhs[i][j]='\0';         
            lhs=str[0];
            char r[20];
            strcpy(r,str+3);
            int j=0;
            for(int i=0;r[i]!='\0';i++)
            {
                if(r[i]!='/')
                rhs[noa][j++]=r[i];
                else
                {
                    rhs[noa++][j]='\0';
                    j=0;
                }
            }
            noa++;
        }
        void checks(string sr)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<30;i++)
            for(int j=0;j<30;j++)
            rs[i][j]=nr[i][j]='\0';     
            int ct=0,k=0,l=0;
            for(int i=0;i<noa;i++)
            {
                if(lhs==rhs[i][0])
                {
                    strcat(rhs[i],sr.c_str());
                    strcpy(rs[k],rhs[i]+1);
                    k++;
                }
                else
                {
                    strcpy(nr[l],rhs[i]);
                    strcat(nr[l],sr.c_str());
                    l++;
                }
            }
            if(l==noa)
            {
                cout<<lhs<<"->";
                for(int i=0;i<noa;i++)
                cout<<rhs[i]<<" ";
                cout<<"\n";
                all[m][0]=lhs;
                strcat(all[m],"->");
                for(int i=0;i<noa;i++)
                {
                    strcat(all[m],rhs[i]);
                    strcat(all[m],"/");
                }
                m++;
            }
            else
            {
                cout<<lhs<<"->";
                for(int i=0;i<l;i++)
                cout<<nr[i]<<" ";
                p.all[m][0]=lhs;
                strcat(all[m],"->");
                for(int i=0;i<l;i++)
                {
                    strcat(all[m],nr[i]);
                    strcat(all[m],"/");
                }
                m++;
                cout<<"\n"<<sr<<"->";
                for(int i=0;i<k;i++)
                cout<<rs[i]<<" ";
                cout<<" e\n";
                all[m][0]=lhs;
                strcat(all[m],"->");
                for(int i=0;i<k;i++)
                {
                    strcat(all[m],rs[i]);
                    strcat(all[m],"/");
                }
                m++;                                
            }
            cout<<"m= "<<m<<"\n";
            for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
            {
                for(int j=0;all[i][j]!='\0';j++)
                cout<<all[i][j];
                cout<<"\n";
            }
        }
        void display()
        {
            cout<<"m= "<<m<<"\n";
            for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
            {
                for(int j=0;all[i][j]!='\0';j++)
                cout<<all[i][j];
                cout<<"\n";
            }
        }
};
int main()
{
    production p;
    char str[20][20];
    string op[5]={"X","Y","Z","U","V"};
    cout<<"enter no of productions\n";
    int n,l=0;
    cin>>n;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cout<<"enter a production\n";
        cin>>str[i];
        p.makeprod(str[i]);
        p.checks(op[l++]);
    }
    p.display();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: without knowing what the intended purpose of the program is, it's hard to tell what is and isn't an error.

Comment: When debugging your code, always try to debug in small chunks, divide this code into smaller pieces and test piece by piece

Comment: Please do not images of text - post the text instead

Comment: Yep Felipe is right. A good fallback is to pick key points in time, and print out all the data at those points. It makes it less of a mystery black box, because you can say "oh something went wrong after this point, but before this other point". After it all works, you can comment out the print statements.

Comment: Can't be bothered to dig through all that to make sure buffers aren't overrun. there are a lot of unprotected strcpy and strcats going on in there.

Comment: In `makeprod` you run `rhs[i][j]` up to 30,30, but it is only 10,10 in size. Likewise in `checks` with `rs` and `nr`.

Comment: Thanq @BoPersson. Its working fine now.Thank you so much.